# How do I delete all Entities of a certain type that I can no longer refer to?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I created a bunch of RandomEntities. Then I deleted the Entity type RandomEntity. Now I have a bunch of different RandomEntities floating around in core data that I can't refer to and they are causing my program to crash when I start it. How can I get rid of these? Is there a way to see all core data through sqlite?

Comment: The simplest way would be to delete your app from the device/simulator. This will remove the database. Otherwise, you will need to add that entity back into your model, delete the objects from core data and then remove the entity from your model

Comment: @Paulw11 That did the trick thank you